# Qt Split QString

Tags: c++, c, qt, qstring

Assume I have a QString like this:

```
[General]
APPLICATION_NAME=skype
Pickup_key=222
Hangup_shift=55
Hangup_key=223
Reject_key=556
Pickup_ctrl=1
```

How would I grab something like ONLY the 222 in Pickup_key and store it into an int? The integer values will dynamically change every time I run the program, so I need to read the number following the "Pickup_key=". I'm reading a `QFile` into a `QString` by the way, that's why it's shaped like this.

Comment: Use [`QTextStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextstream.html) to read the string (or the file) line by line. There is also [`QSettings`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsettings.html) which can already read a file in this format (INI).

Comment: I have the program reading it line by line, but how do I seperate the "Pickup_key=" and the "222"?

Comment: `QString name = line.section("=", 0, 1); QString value = line.section("=", 1, -1);`

Comment: Do you try to read a settings file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the following class to read and handle your string (actually it looks like an ini format):

```
class IniReader
{
public:
    IniReader(const QString &input)
    {
        // Split by \n first.
        QStringList lines = input.split('\n');
        foreach (const QString &line, lines) {
            // Split line by '='.
            QStringList tokens = line.split('=', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
            if (tokens.size() == 2) {
                m_data.insert(tokens.at(0), tokens.at(1));
            }
        }
    }

    QVariant data(const QString &key) const {
        return m_data.value(key);
    }
private:
    QMap<QString, QVariant> m_data;
};
```

And here is how to use it:

```
IniReader reader("[General]\n" \
                 "APPLICATION_NAME=skype\n" \
                 "Pickup_key=222\n" \
                 "Hangup_shift=55\n" \
                 "Hangup_key=223\n" \
                 "Reject_key=556\n" \
                 "Pickup_ctrl=1");

int Pickup_key = reader.data("Pickup_key").toInt();
```

And, as already suggested by other guys, you can use `QSettings` to read and handle your file's data. Here is an example:

```
QSettings settings("test.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
int Pickup_key2 = settings.value("Pickup_key").toInt();
```

Where test.ini file contains your sample string.